# Installing Orfeo toolbox for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, installation, windows-8, orfeo-toolbox

I installed QGIS through OSGeo4W 64 bit version in Windows 8.

QGIS installed correctly, but I cannot add the Orfeo Toolbox.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE! From the toolbar, did you try going through _Processing_ > _Options and Configuration_ > _Providers_ > _Orfeo Toolbox_ and checking the **Activate** box?

Comment: Yes I did. After installation I tried to add it through  Processing>Options>Providers>Orfeo Toolbox and checked the Activate box. But its not showing up.

Comment: Hopefully others can advise as I use Windows 7 and not able to replicate it.

Answer (score 1):

This is still an issue in late 2016 but there is an answer. Its not too difficult but it may look at little intimidating. You will have to install the full OSGeo package (from the QGIS website). You will need the advanced install, not the convenient, quick installer. During the installation you will be shown a list of packages to install. Those with "keep" next to them you should keep. Scroll down the list until you get to OTG orfeo and then click on the lastest version of it so that it will be installed. Browse the list for anything else you might need.
See this ticket for more info:
http://hub.qgis.org/issues/14802

Note that the standard install for Mac from KyngChaos has Orfeo installed by default, which seems a more sensible way of doing things.